# Xero API C# asp.net does not save the input from user to fields in contacts in Xero

Tags: c#, xero-api

I am writing an app that takes user input to create a new contact to the connected org's xero
contacts. I have managed to make it so that when you click on create contact it displays my contact form  [Contact form][1]

I have used some of the code and added some. The API call posts the data of the primary person and the contact person . however the rest of the  details such as address and phone is not being saved, would you be able to help with this please . I'm very new to developing .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KompleteMe.Models;
using KompleteMe.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Api;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Model.Accounting;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Token;

namespace KompleteMe.Controllers
{
    public class ContactsInfo : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<XeroAuthorizationController> _logger;
        private readonly IOptions<XeroConfiguration> XeroConfig;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

        public ContactsInfo(IOptions<XeroConfiguration> XeroConfig, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ILogger<XeroAuthorizationController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.XeroConfig = XeroConfig;
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        // GET: /ContactsInfo/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        // GET: /ContactsInfo#Create
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var contact = new ContactModel();
            return View(contact);
        }

        // POST: /ContactsInfo#Create
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ContactModel model)
        {
            var xeroToken = TokenUtilities.GetStoredToken();
            var utcTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (utcTimeNow > xeroToken.ExpiresAtUtc)
            {
                var client = new XeroClient(XeroConfig.Value, httpClientFactory);
                xeroToken = (XeroOAuth2Token)await client.RefreshAccessTokenAsync(xeroToken);
                TokenUtilities.StoreToken(xeroToken);
            }

            string accessToken = xeroToken.AccessToken;
            string xeroTenantId = xeroToken.Tenants[0].TenantId.ToString();
            var contactp = new ContactPerson();
            var contact = new Contact();
            var phone = new Phone();
            var address = new Address();
            contact.Name = model.Name;
            contact.FirstName=model.FirstName;
            contact.LastName = model.LastName;
            contact.EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress;
            //Contact person .
            contactp.FirstName = model.PersonFirstName;
            contactp.LastName = model.PersonLastName;
            contactp.EmailAddress = model.PersonEmailAddress;
            phone.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
            phone.PhoneCountryCode = model.PhoneCountryCode;
            address.AddressLine1 = model.AddressLine1;
            address.City = model.City;
            address.PostalCode = model.PostalCode;
           // contact.Website = model.Website;
            contact.ContactPersons  = new List<ContactPerson>();
            contact.ContactPersons.Add(contactp);
            contact.TaxNumber = model.TaxNumber;
            contact.Phones = new List<Phone>();
            contact.Phones.Add(phone);

            contact.Addresses = new List<Address>();
            contact.Addresses.Add(address);

            var contacts = new Contacts();
            
            contacts._Contacts = new List<Contact>() { contact };

            var AccountingApi = new AccountingApi();
            var response = await AccountingApi.CreateContactsAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, contacts);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ContactsInfo");
        }
    }
}



  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using RestSharp.Validation;
    
    namespace KompleteMe.Models
    {
        public class ContactModel
        {
          
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Lastname is required")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required")]
            public string PersonFirstName{ get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lasttname is required")]
            public string PersonLastName { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
            public string PersonEmailAddress { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "tax is required")]
            public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "phone is required")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "phonecode is required")]
            public string PhoneCountryCode { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "addressline1 is required")]
            public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "city is required")]
            public string City { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "postalcode is required")]
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            public string Website { get; set; }
        }
    }

 

@model ContactModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Contact</h4>
<hr />
<form asp-action="Create">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label">Company Name </label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label">Email Address </label>
                <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Contact Person </h4>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PersonFirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <input asp-for="PersonFirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PersonFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>


                <label asp-for="PersonEmailAddress" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                <input asp-for="PersonEmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PersonEmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>

                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="control-label"> Phone Number</label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>



                <label asp-for="PhoneCountryCode" class="control-label">Phone Country Code </label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneCountryCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneCountryCode" class="text-danger"></span>

                <label asp-for="TaxNumber" class="control-label">Vat Number </label>
                <input asp-for="TaxNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxNumber" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PersonLastName" class="control-label">Last Name </label>
                <input asp-for="PersonLastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PersonLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label asp-for="AddressLine1" class="control-label"> Street Address </label>
                <input asp-for="AddressLine1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AddressLine1" class="text-danger"></span>

                <label asp-for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>

                <label asp-for="PostalCode" class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
                <input asp-for="PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label asp-for="Website" class="control-label">Website</label>
                <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Website" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

















</form>




@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: thanks, apologies . should have thought of that .